# How to get PHP 7.0 running with Apache2

Tags: server, 16.04, lamp, php7

I am totally new to Linux, servers and websites. I recently set up Apache2, Python, PHP, and MySQL for setting up a LAMP server. I am using Xubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0.11. I followed a guide and placed a PHP file named testing.php in it with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

It doesn't show anything on `localhost/testing.php` All it shows is the code itself.

Comment: Er... what is your question here?

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?>                            This is the code i used. The page should show the details of PHP. But all it shows is the code itself

Comment: Even if you can't embed images into your posts before you earned enough reputation you can always include links to images in your posts (not too many though because that'll trigger the spam filter but you'll know how many is too many when you try to submit your post).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0 # install PHP7 module for Apache2 webserver
sudo a2enmod php7.0 # enable the PHP7 module
sudo service apache2 reload # restart apache
```

For PHP 7.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2  
sudo a2enmod php7.2  
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: I had to disable mpm_event to make it works:
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
(php7.0 enable mpm_prefork)