# apache2 is up and running but my php code cant run

Tags: apache2

I can't open my php code on my web browser even when my apache2 server is up and running
i started apache2, and put my php code in the apt/lamp/htdocs folder but still it doesn't work

Comment: Do your php code show up in the browser? Is an error shown? Please add the informations to the questions, not in the comments!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PHP 7.0 running with Apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825569/how-to-get-php-7-0-running-with-apache2)