# Info.php in the root directory of my website forbidden

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I wanted to check the used php version with a info.php file in the root directory of my Mautic installation, but i get an error: https://ma.stefan-franz.de/info.php
File content: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

What is the reason for this or what do i have to adjust to get access (or how do i find out it)?

In the
/var/log/apache2/error.log

i found this entry:

```
[Wed Nov 15 17:06:28.407189 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 83665] [client 2a02:3037:2e0:47f8:4be4:7270:daa1:35d3:37652] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/mautic/info.php
```

Comment: This doesn’t really have anything to do with Ubuntu but your Apache configuration. So this question is better suited on a different site. Meanwhile, perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration#19588786

Comment: From the error message, apache is finding the file. What are the file's permissions? What are the directory's permissions? Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get PHP 7.0 running with Apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825569/how-to-get-php-7-0-running-with-apache2)