# when I navigate to http://localhost/phpmyadmin I get this on the browser, this is after setting up phpmyadmin, mysql and apache2 in WSL ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get this error on the browser while running `phpmyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;
if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}
global $route, $containerBuilder;
require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';
$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

Comment: Welcome! You haven' provided a single detail that could give a clue. For starters, it would be good to know how you installed phpMyAdmin (and related programs like webserver etc). However, it seems to me that maybe the PHP module isn't actually active on your webserver, and that it simply shows PHP as normal text.

Comment: I have done everything, installed mysql-server and create a user, installed apache and started the server all this in wsl ubuntu for windows, I also have phpmyadmin installed

Comment: Please include detailed in formation in your question. And you're sure the PHP module is enabled? Please provide evidence (screen output). Thanks. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get PHP 7.0 running with Apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825569/how-to-get-php-7-0-running-with-apache2)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is the PHP version you are using?

Comment: You are probably missing `libapache2-mod-php` (https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu#known-issues)